# Maven Error " annotations are not supported....."

Tags: spring, netbeans, jakarta-ee, maven

This is one of the most annoying errors ? What I can understand is that I am using a lower version of Java for compiling. How can I specify java version for maven ?

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project
>   springAopMavenDemo: Compilation
>   failure D:\JAVA
>   Stuffs\projects\springAopMavenDemo\src\main\java\service\EmployeeServiceImpl.java:[13,1]
>   annotations are not supported in
>   -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations) @Service
>   -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the
>   errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X
>   switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors
>   and possible solutions, please read
>   the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

I really appreciate any help......I am using NetBeans 7.0 and Maven 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell maven which version of java the source should be compiled to

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: This is true also make sure maven settings are fine, although mine where and in intellij and it was still doing this

Comment: I don't understand why isn't 1.5 the default .. do we all have to get this error ..

Answer (score 1):

You are using some annotated code in your java, but  compiling in your ide is using source java 1.3 by passing an additional commandline parameter most likely
I had the same thing in intellij a while back

In netbeans config (sorry I am not a netbeans person) find where jdk/compiler setup is and change the command line arg

Update: quick net serach says it may be under Properties > Build > Compiling

Answer (score 1):

emeraldjava answer is correct. However, I want to add two things:

First, you can set the source and target information as Maven properties:

```
<build>
    ...
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
```

Second, if you use the latest version of the Maven compiler plugin (2.3.2 for example), the default version for compiler is 1.5, so you will not need any additional configuration:

> The Compiler Plugin is used to compile
>   the sources of your project. The
>   default compiler is javac and is used
>   to compile Java sources. Also note
>   that at present the default source
>   setting is 1.5 and the default target
>   setting is 1.5, independently of the
>   JDK you run Maven with.

([source](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/))